# Get data with a c program from an HTML form

Tags: html, c, forms

I have created the following C program to get data from an HTML form. But when I try to compile and run it, I get:

> segmentation fault 11 (core dumped)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
int main()
{
    char *N1,*N2,*N3,*N4,*N5;
    int cgi_length;
    char *cgi_data;
    printf("Content-type:text/html\n\n");
    cgi_length=atoi(getenv("CONTENT_LENGTH"));
    cgi_data=malloc(cgi_length+1);
    fread(cgi_data,1,cgi_length,stdin);
    printf("<HTML>");
    printf("<HEAD><TITLE>DATA</TITLE></HEAD><BODY>\n");
    printf("<H3>DATA</H3>\n");
    if(cgi_data == NULL)
    {
        printf("<P>Error! Error in passing data from form to script.");
    }
    else {
        printf("%s",cgi_data);
        sscanf(cgi_data,"N1=%s&N2=%s&N3=%S&N4=%SN5=%s",&N1,&N2,&N3,&N4,&N5);
        printf("<P>N1 is %s and N2 is %s and N3 is %S and N4 is %S and N5 is %s.",N1,N2,N3,N4,N5);
    }
}
```

Also if I use the `ls` command to see the data in the *cgi-bin* directory I see that a file named *myprogram.cgi.core* is created.

Does anyone know what is wrong?

Comment: Put some messages on STDERR to see where the seg fault occurs.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem before. I used `fgets` in a `while` loop. `fread` didn't work for me. Try this:

```
cgi_length=atoi(getenv("CONTENT_LENGTH"));
    cgi_data=malloc(cgi_length+1);
    while(fgets(cgi_data,cgi_length,stdin)!=NULL){
//insert some processing here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Load the coredump in GDB. Try something like:

```
 gdb myprogram.cgi myprogram.cgi.core
```

maybe replace myprogram.cgi with the proper name of the CGI.

When you are in GDB you could get a back trace to see where the application crashed by typing `bt` in the console.

Here you can find a quick tutorial on howto GDB: http://cs.baylor.edu/~donahoo/tools/gdb/tutorial.html

Few notes...:

- Check what `getenv` returns, maybe it returns NULL instead of the value of the environment variable.
- `sscanf` copies the values of the strings to the buffers where `N1 N2 N3 N4 N5` are pointing to, it would be wise to allocate some memory for those pointers first...
- You don't have to get the reference of the points `N1 N2 N3 N4 N5`
- As Daniel Fischer noted: fread doesn't 0 terminate the string.

Answer (score 0):

You have to check that the return value of your `getenv` function call is not a null pointer. Passing a null pointer to `atoi` is undefined behavior. I suggest also to check the return value of all your function calls and to use `strtol` function instead of `atoi` because `atoi` cannot detect errors.

Answer (score 0):

If you compile with -Wall (all warnings), it will give you an idea what's wrong

```
cgi.c: In function ‘main’:
cgi.c:23:9: warning: format ‘%s’ expects argument of type ‘char *’, but argument 3 has type ‘char **’ [-Wformat]
cgi.c:23:9: warning: format ‘%s’ expects argument of type ‘char *’, but argument 4 has type ‘char **’ [-Wformat]
cgi.c:23:9: warning: format ‘%S’ expects argument of type ‘wchar_t *’, but argument 5 has type ‘char **’ [-Wformat]
cgi.c:23:9: warning: format ‘%S’ expects argument of type ‘wchar_t *’, but argument 6 has type ‘char **’ [-Wformat]
cgi.c:23:9: warning: format ‘%s’ expects argument of type ‘char *’, but argument 7 has type ‘char **’ [-Wformat]
cgi.c:24:9: warning: format ‘%S’ expects argument of type ‘wchar_t *’, but argument 4 has type ‘char *’ [-Wformat]
cgi.c:24:9: warning: format ‘%S’ expects argument of type ‘wchar_t *’, but argument 5 has type ‘char *’ [-Wformat]
cgi.c:26:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several fundamental C programming errors. Use e.g. lint to find out some of them. For example, you’re declaring N1 as a character pointer but do not initialize it, and you pass its address as argument. You need to allocate a character array somehow and pass a pointer to it as an argument to sscanf.

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure that you are getting zero in this line

```
cgi_length=atoi(getenv("CONTENT_LENGTH"));
```

Check if there is this environment variable actually defined. And always check for sizes before allocating memory and before putting some data into it.